# PHP exec() , showing executed exe file in task manager but not displaying

Tags: php, exec, executable

i have used simple PHP script to execute exe file through php script, below is my PHP code

```
<? exec('"C:\Windows\notepad.exe"');?>
```

my problem is, when i check task manager after executing above code, notepad.exe is there but it is not diplaying

same way if i execute below mentioned code

```
<?  exec('"C:\Program Files\WinSCP\WinSCP.exe"'); ?>
```

task manager shows WinSCP.exe, but winscp is not diplaying

can anyone tell me why applications are not showing ?

Comment: Works for me. I guess you are using a web server as proxy and Notepad is showing up (or trying) in the desktop of the user it runs as (maybe local system account) :-?

Comment: i am in administrator account

Comment: Belonging to the Administrator group doesn't mean an user doesn't have any boundary or restriction. For instance, an admin cannot see all the GUI apps from all users that are currently running on the computer (if that was possible, how could he even use the computer?). I'll try to clarify my information request since I wasn't clear. Are you loading your PHP from the command-line or using a web browser? What user does Task Manager report for the `notepad.exe` process?

Comment: i am running through browser. 
i checked in task manger, for notepad.exe and winscp.exe it is showing SYSTEM in username column, it should be administrator there

Answer (score 1):

Whatever your web server is (Apache, Nginx, IIS...) it's clearly not configured to run with the credentials of your *administrator* user account. That's the sensible default. Background services are designed to run unattended.

You have several choice, from worse to better:

1. Kill security in your web server configuration. If web server runs as service, open Windows Service Manager and configure it to run with your account (don't forget to come back here if you change your password in the future). This way you allow any stranger in your computer, local network and/or internet to run programs in your name, in this case Notepad and WinSCP.
2. If the web server allows it, run it from a command-prompt in your own session. It's similar to #1 but will at least not run 24/7.
3. Any of the above, with a restricted account.
4. Don't use a web server. PHP can run from the command-line just fine, what means that you can even create a *.bat file and assign an icon to it.

As about your code, when it finally works your script will sleep until you close Notepad. This can be a bug or a feature depending on your needs.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem with WAMP 2.4 & windows XP, the following helped:

Win+R, services.msc

edit wampapache and wampmysqld to allow affecting desktop.

Alternatively you can try:

Win+R, services.msc

edit wampapache and wampmysqld to log on as the same user.